# HTTP.sys namespace reservation for external domain user

Tags: windows, access-control-list

What I'm trying to do is add a namespace reservation on port 8080 for an user that is in an external domain (accessible only via VPN):

> netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8080/SomeApi
>   user="EXTERNALDOMAIN\username" listen=yes delegate=yes

The error is:

> Create SDDL failed, Error: 1332  The parameter is incorrect.

The thing is that the app that needs to listen on 8080 locally, needs to run under this remote account (via `runas /netonly`). It then connects through a VPN, with Windows Auth to various other systems (SQL Server, etc.), so it needs to run under this remote account.

However, I cannot find a way to add a namespace reservation for that particular user. Any way this could work?

Comment: I needed a solution to this really quick so for now I just granted that reservation to `Everyone`. That's right, `user=Everyone`. This is acceptable because it's a development computer. But if anybody has a proper solution or explanation as to why it's not possible, then please go ahead and post.

Comment: Does you can add EXTERNALDOMAIN\user's security in file share too? As the system need to translate that entry to the SID, but can't do that if the domain is not reachable when you add the entry